# Unable to store bytes data to sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, google-cloud-sql

I am planning to store hashed value of password in SQL Server database when a user signs up and when the same user logs in, will compare user entered password with the stored hashed value.

I am using following piece of code to generate hashed value of password and want to insert same value in the database with column datatype `varbinary(1000)`.

[image]

I have used following code snippets to insert into database and both options have failed.

```
insert into users.dbo.allusers values (123456789, 
b'\xc8\xc2\x06\x9f\x8e\x96\xad\xb3\x14r\x97Rm"\'\xfdbt\x03\xc81F\xc59\xd03\xcfXs\x88\xff\x95bg\x7f\xd1\xf6\xfc\x98\xe5x~c\x9eb\x91\x89\x80{\x14i0\x99f&\xa5\\e?\xf2\xbd\x06\xf7\xd0', 
'a@a.com',
'a', 
'b'
)
```

```
insert into users.dbo.allusers values (123456789, 
convert(varbinary(1000), b'\xc8\xc2\x06\x9f\x8e\x96\xad\xb3\x14r\x97Rm"\'\xfdbt\x03\xc81F\xc59\xd03\xcfXs\x88\xff\x95bg\x7f\xd1\xf6\xfc\x98\xe5x~c\x9eb\x91\x89\x80{\x14i0\x99f&\xa5\\e?\xf2\xbd\x06\xf7\xd0', 1), 
'a@a.com',
'a', 
'b'
)
```

The error I am getting is

> SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '\xc8\xc2\x06\x9f\x8e\x96\xad\xb3\x14r\x97Rm"'.

I am using cloudsql (gcp product) with SQL Server 2017 standard and dbeaver client to insert data. Any help is really appreciated.

Based on comments I am editing my question. Also used python to insert data to SQL Server using following flask code

```
def generate_password(password_value):
    salt = os.urandom(32)
    key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password_value.encode('utf-8'), salt, 100000)

    # Store them as:
    storage = salt + key 
    return storage

@app.route('/add_new_user', methods = ['POST'])
def add_new_user():
    data = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    cpf = data.get('cpf')
    password = data.get('password')
    email = data.get('email')
    fname = data.get('fname')
    lname = data.get('lname')
    password = generate_password(password)


    mssqlhost = '127.0.0.1'
    mssqluser = 'sqlserver'
    mssqlpass = 'sqlserver'
    mssqldb = 'users'

    try:
        # - [x] Establish Connection to db
        mssqlconn = pymssql.connect(
            mssqlhost, mssqluser, mssqlpass, mssqldb)
        print("Connection Established to MS SQL server.")
        cursor = mssqlconn.cursor()
        stmt  = "insert into users.dbo.allusers (cpf, password, email, fname, lname) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        data = f'({cpf}, {password}, {email}, {fname}, {lname})'
        print(data)
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        mssqlconn.commit()
        mssqlconn.close()
        return {"success":"true"}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"success":"false"}
```

I get different error in command prompt

> more placeholders in sql than params available

because data already has quotes because of hash value (printed data)

```
(123456789, b'6\x17DnOP\xbb\xd0\xdbL\xb6"}\xda6M\x1dX\t\xdd\x12\xec\x059\xbb\xe1/\x1c|\xea\x038\xfd\r\xd1\xcbt\xd6Pe\xcd<W\n\x9f\x89\xd7J\xc1\xbb\xe1\xd0\xd2n\xa7j}\xf7\xf5:\xba0\xab\xbe', a@a.com, a, b)
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: This looks like you are injecting your strings, not parametrising them. Also, a string isn't prefixed with a `b` in T-SQL. The only allowed prefix is `N` (not `n`) which is the notation character for `nvarchar`. Posting your actual code that generates the SQL will help us help you, and *not* as an image. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @larnu i have edited my question and iam accepting data in parameters. But still getting error and i feel its because of bytes data. I saw this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552677/sql-query-throws-identifier-is-too-long-maximum-length-is-128/28552717 and it says convert quotes. I need data to store as is because its hashed value of password.

Comment: `stmt  = f"insert into users.dbo.allusers values ({cpf}, {password}, {email}, {fname}, {lname})` That isn't a parametrised query. That's injection.

Comment: Have a read of the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pymssql/ref/pymssql.html#cusor-object-methods) on how to pass parameters using pymssql.

Comment: Thankyou @Larnu i have modified code as below
stmt  = "insert into users.dbo.allusers (cpf, password, email, fname, lname) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
 data = ({cpf}, {password}, {email}, {fname}, {lname})
 cursor.execute(stmt, data)

I did not get error but data is not inserted

Comment: Try something like this `cursor.execute("SELECT %s AS SomeString;", StringVariable)`. You can replace `SELECT %s AS SomeString;` with your statement variable.

Comment: sorry i see error now "more placeholders in sql than params available". Also i printed data
(123456789, b'6\x17DnOP\xbb\xd0\xdbL\xb6"}\xda6M\x1dX\t\xdd\x12\xec\x059\xbb\xe1/\x1c|\xea\x038\xfd\r\xd1\xcbt\xd6Pe\xcd<W\n\x9f\x89\xd7J\xc1\xbb\xe1\xd0\xd2n\xa7j}\xf7\xf5:\xba0\xab\xbe', a@a.com, a, b)
The data itself has quotes and that's the reason its breaking. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary literal in TSQL looks like `0x0A23...`

```
insert into dbo.allusers(cpf, password, email, fname, lname) 
values 
(
  123456789, 
  0xC8C2069F8E96. . .,
  'a@a.com',
  'a', 
  'b'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when iam using library to generate hash of password, iam getting that text as output. If the output i got is not binary, how should i store it in sqlserver?

Comment: @sandeep007 - Base64 encode the binary and store as VARCHAR.

Comment: Thanks David and John. I used different algorithm to generate password and stored it as string.